# How to fix this IO bound python operation on 12GB .bin file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, binaryfiles, algorithmic-trading

I'm reading this book [Hands-On Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JLFH7C5) and I came across a script that is supposed to parse a large `.bin` binary file and convert it to `.h5`. This file consists of something called ITCH data, you can find the technical documentation of the data [here](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/NQTVITCHSpecification.pdf). The script is very inefficient, it reads a 12GB(12952050754 bytes) file 2 bytes at a time which is ultra slow(might take up to 4 hours on some decent 4cpu GCP instance) which is not very surprising. You can find the whole notebook [here](https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/master/02_market_and_fundamental_data/01_NASDAQ_TotalView-ITCH_Order_Book/01_parse_itch_order_flow_messages.ipynb).

My problem is I don't understand how this `.bin` file is being read I mean I don't see where is the necessity of reading the file 2 bytes at a time, I think there is a way to read at a large buffer size but I'm not sure how to do it, or even convert the script to c++ if after optimizing this script, it is still being slow which I can do if I understand the inner workings of this I/O process, does anyone have suggestions?

here's a link to the file [source](ftp://emi.nasdaq.com/) of ITCH data, you can find small files(300 mb or less) which are for less time periods if you need to experiment with the code.

---

The bottleneck:

```
with file_name.open('rb') as data:
    while True:

        # determine message size in bytes
        message_size = int.from_bytes(data.read(2), byteorder='big', signed=False)
        
        # get message type by reading first byte
        message_type = data.read(1).decode('ascii')        
        message_type_counter.update([message_type])

        # read & store message
        record = data.read(message_size - 1)
        message = message_fields[message_type]._make(unpack(fstring[message_type], record))
        messages[message_type].append(message)
        
        # deal with system events
        if message_type == 'S':
            seconds = int.from_bytes(message.timestamp, byteorder='big') * 1e-9
            print('\n', event_codes.get(message.event_code.decode('ascii'), 'Error'))
            print(f'\t{format_time(seconds)}\t{message_count:12,.0f}')
            if message.event_code.decode('ascii') == 'C':
                store_messages(messages)
                break
        message_count += 1

        if message_count % 2.5e7 == 0:
            seconds = int.from_bytes(message.timestamp, byteorder='big') * 1e-9
            d = format_time(time() - start)
            print(f'\t{format_time(seconds)}\t{message_count:12,.0f}\t{d}')
            res = store_messages(messages)
            if res == 1:
                print(pd.Series(dict(message_type_counter)).sort_values())
                break
            messages.clear()
```

And here's the `store_messages()` function:

```
def store_messages(m):
    """Handle occasional storing of all messages"""
    with pd.HDFStore(itch_store) as store:
        for mtype, data in m.items():
            # convert to DataFrame
            data = pd.DataFrame(data)

            # parse timestamp info
            data.timestamp = data.timestamp.apply(int.from_bytes, byteorder='big')
            data.timestamp = pd.to_timedelta(data.timestamp)

            # apply alpha formatting
            if mtype in alpha_formats.keys():
                data = format_alpha(mtype, data)

            s = alpha_length.get(mtype)
            if s:
                s = {c: s.get(c) for c in data.columns}
            dc = ['stock_locate']
            if m == 'R':
                dc.append('stock')
            try:
                store.append(mtype,
                         data,
                         format='t',
                         min_itemsize=s,
                         data_columns=dc)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print(mtype)
                print(data.info())
                print(pd.Series(list(m.keys())).value_counts())
                data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
                return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, file format looks like its 2 bytes of message size, one byte of message type and then n bytes of actual message (defined by the previously read message size).

Low hanging fruit to optimize this is to read 3 bytes first into list, convert [0:1] to message size int and [2] to message type  and then read the message ..

To further eliminate amount of required reads, you could read a fixed amount of data from the file into a list of and start extracting from it.  While extracting, keep a index of already processed bytes stored and once that index or index+amount of data to be read goes over the size of the list, you prepopulate the list. This could lead to huge memory requirements if not done properly thought..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, let me reflect my thoughts: let's say for example I'll read 100 mb(100000000 bytes) at a time, then I'll do something like `current_read = data.read(100000000)` then I might partition the list using another function that knows where's what, convert & store the list contents using a third and a fourth function, then maybe at the end, clear the list and save the last index in a variable. The problem is how to ensure it's behaving correctly? I mean even running this in the debugger won't give indications of whether it's working fine. Any better / faster ways?

Comment: Can you provide some code clarifying your explanation further?

Comment: FWIW that's unlikely to do anything: Python's binary file IO is fully buffered by default, using a buffer of `os.stat(path).st_blksize` if available, otherwise `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`. So the small `read`s are just going to update the buffer, the underlying file is read 4k/8k at a time. If you want a larger buffer (at the cost of more memory consumption) you can providen a larger buffer size to `open`, but I wouldn't be optimistic. I'd recommend using a profiler to try and find out exactly what the hotspots are (in case there are hotspots)